# Index/Search PDF content with Solr

Tags: pdf, solr

I'm experimenting with Solr and I've encountered this issue:

I've indexed a PDF document and when I search for ":" in the admin console, the PDF is listed. However when I search for content within the PDF I get no results.

To index the document, I used copy-and-paste code from: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ContentStreamUpdateRequestExample

Answer (score 2):

use this command

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?stream.file=/home/fstl/apache-solr-3.2.0/example/exampledocs/pup.pdf&stream.contentType=application/pdf&literal.id=esc.doc&commit=true"
```